# What does include latest previous release in google play mean?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

What does `include a latest previous release in Google Play mean`?

I'm publishing an update to my app and when uploading the new `app bundle` Google Play shows this:-

[image]

After Scrolling down

[image]

So I have one question!

> What will happen if I include my previous release vs if I didn't?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A release is a combination of one or more build artifacts that you'll prepare to roll out an app or an app update.

1 example of this would be a release that comes as a Wear OS aab and normal android aab.

For your case, you probably only have a single artifact, so you always use the latest one.